# how to dispose DomainContext?

Tags: wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

DomainContext consumes many memory when an instance created. If the instance is local variable, looks like the memory not released automatically with following code:

```
MyDomainContext  ctx = new MyDomainContext();
....
ctx=null;
```

How to release a memory for the instance of a DomainContext?

Answer (score 1):

DomainContext doesn't implements IDisposable so you must rely on GarbageCollector to free up your memory. Be sure to remove any reference to the DomainContext instance than call `System.GC.Collect()`

 You shouldn't bother about the entities loaded by the domaincontext and still referenced somewhere in the code, as long as I know WCF Ria services keep only a WeakReference to them